# A question on the relation between the complex zeroes of zeta function and the estimate of the error in PNT

Tags: analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I'm currently working on the following problem from Analytic Number Theory.

> Assume that $\psi(x)-x=\mathcal{O}(x^a)$, for some $1/2<a<1$, where
> $\psi$ is the Chebyshev function.
>
> I would like to show that this implies that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeroes
> with $\sigma>a$, where $s=\sigma+it$.

I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof of this claim. Any hint/help will be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Simply use that $s \int_1^\infty (\psi(x)-x)x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} -\frac{s}{s-1}$, for $\Re(s) > 1$, and by analytic continuation for $\Re(s) > a$ under your assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This may seem trivial (or, may be it is), but how does the analytic continuation for $\sigma>a$ imply that $\zeta(s)\neq0$?

Comment: If $\zeta(\rho)=0$ then $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $\rho$

Comment: @reuns Got it, thanks!